# blue screen of death MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT

Tags: windows

I get bsod at least once a day on my new PC and i ran a mini dump and it says MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT. I don't know exactly whats causing this to happen i got my PC about 2 weeks ago please help me.

this is a desktop that was already built before i bought it, it has 32gb of ram and an i9 9900k

This is what the mini dump file says about why i got the BSOD

```
MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000041792, A corrupt PTE has been detected. Parameter 2 contains the address of
    the PTE. Parameters 3/4 contain the low/high parts of the PTE.
Arg2: ffffbc80b7bdc240
Arg3: 0000000000000002
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


PROCESSES_ANALYSIS: 1

SERVICE_ANALYSIS: 1

STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 41792

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffbc80b7bdc240

BUGCHECK_P3: 2

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  ONE_BIT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1a_41792

CPU_COUNT: 10

CPU_MHZ: e10

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 9e

CPU_STEPPING: d

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  firefox.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-OBF6H0I

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  01-31-2020 21:17:43.0041

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.18362.1 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffbd07`4fa1ee28 fffff807`0fa252ee : 00000000`0000001a 00000000`00041792 ffffbc80`b7bdc240 00000000`00000002 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffbd07`4fa1ee30 fffff807`0f8ac9e7 : 00000000`00000000 ffffbc80`b7bdc240 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiDeleteVa+0x176b0e
ffffbd07`4fa1ef40 fffff807`0f8acea1 : ffffbd07`4fa1f390 ffffbcde`405bdee0 00000000`00000000 0a000003`22de5867 : nt!MiWalkPageTablesRecursively+0x1e7
ffffbd07`4fa1f000 fffff807`0f8acea1 : ffffbd07`4fa1f390 ffffbcde`6f202de8 00000000`00000000 0a000007`ffbae867 : nt!MiWalkPageTablesRecursively+0x6a1
ffffbd07`4fa1f0c0 fffff807`0f8acea1 : ffffbd07`4fa1f390 ffffbcde`6f379010 ffffbcde`00000000 0a000004`6c7ad867 : nt!MiWalkPageTablesRecursively+0x6a1
ffffbd07`4fa1f180 fffff807`0f8ac62c : ffffbd07`4fa1f390 1a000007`ffbae867 00000000`00000000 ffffac8e`6b3546c0 : nt!MiWalkPageTablesRecursively+0x6a1
ffffbd07`4fa1f240 fffff807`0f8aaa98 : ffffbd07`4fa1f390 ffff9c80`00000002 00000000`00000001 fffff807`00000000 : nt!MiWalkPageTables+0x36c
ffffbd07`4fa1f340 fffff807`0f8b8bf0 : ffffffff`ffffffff ffffac8e`6b354438 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiDeletePagablePteRange+0x268
ffffbd07`4fa1f6e0 fffff807`0fdc7a5d : 0000016f`00000000 00000000`16f7b140 ffffac8e`72d92440 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiDeleteVad+0x860
ffffbd07`4fa1f8a0 fffff807`0fdc7853 : ffffac8e`72d92440 00000000`00000000 0000016f`7b140000 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiUnmapVad+0x49
ffffbd07`4fa1f8d0 fffff807`0fdc76e9 : ffffac8e`6b3540c0 00000000`00000008 ffffac8e`4f0aabc0 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiUnmapViewOfSection+0x133
ffffbd07`4fa1f9b0 fffff807`0f9d2d15 : ffffac8e`7037b080 0000016f`7b140000 0000016f`7b7a72f0 ffffac8e`6b3540c0 : nt!NtUnmapViewOfSectionEx+0x99
ffffbd07`4fa1fa00 00007ffc`007bf974 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
0000005d`59ffd9d8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffc`007bf974


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  cd17d96308226c0911d4c2e72141f4a08060b33a

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  68d7355f1c7999b99638818b39e5354b1f1c76bd

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  fe34192f63d13620a8987d294372ee74d699cfee

SYMBOL_NAME:  ONE_BIT

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: hardware

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT

BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT

TARGET_TIME:  2020-02-01T04:36:42.000Z

OSBUILD:  18362

OSSERVICEPACK:  592

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  784

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  1972-08-21 17:24:00

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  190318-1202

BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  121e

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:memory_corruption_one_bit

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {e3faf315-c3d0-81db-819a-6c43d23c63a7}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: Hello there and thanks for posting on superuser. Please add your pc type (laptop, desktop) as well as it's hardware (CPU, RAM, HDD, SSD, etc.) Also, is this a custom build or a prefabricated PC?

Comment: this is a desktop that was already built before i bought it, it has 32gb of ram and an i9 9900k

Comment: What about your SSD or HDD?

Comment: This might also be an overclocking error...please post a screenshot of your Task Manager on the performance tab if possible.

Comment: Return your PC for repair. It not your problem but the shops.

Answer (score 1):

```
BUGCHECK_STR: 0x1a_41792
```

https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/memory-corruption-one-bit-large-bsod.2828014/

> The error code 41792 indicates a corrupted page table entry.

This means something isn't right with your HDD/SSD. You need to verify everything related to your disk drives.

First: **Check your SATA cables**. Possibly a SATA cable is incorrectly connected. Or an **M.2 drive is not inserted correctly.**

If all checks out, verify your SMART integrity with an app like [Crystaldiskinfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/). Update your SATA or chipset drivers as well.

Comment: Good find! After I experienced for the first time this error, I noticed that 2 of my HDD/SSD have SMART errors.